# Enlace ancla en scroll web dirije más abajo del id correspondiente

Tags: html5, enlaces-ancla

El siguiente enlace ancla:

```
<li class="active"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
```

Dirije más abajo de dónde yo quiero:

```
<div id="home">
<!-- Slider Starts -->
<div class="banner">
<div class="caja">
    <div class="videoContainer">
      <div class="imagen-video"></div>
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-LRlMcUbDwY?modestbranding=1&autoplay=1&controls=0&fs=0&loop=1&playlist=-LRlMcUbDwY&rel=0&showinfo=1&disablekb=1&iv_load_policy=0&start=0.8" frameborder="0"></iframe>
          <div class="caption">
            <div class="caption-wrapper">
              <div class="caption-info">              
              <h1 class="animated bounceInUp">Dream Nature</h1>
              <p class="animated bounceInLeft">Feel Nature Live Adventures</p>
              <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AfSsWDMOtOI&index=4&list=LLZKl8y7fBQ1sCqcdO79S4Rw&t=1s" class="btnfull">Full Video</a>
              <a href="#about" class="explore animated bounceInDown"><i class="fa fa-angle-down  fa-3x"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>    
<!-- </div> -->
<!-- #Slider Ends -->
</div>

<!-- ABOUT US SECTION -->
<div id="about"  class="container-fluid spacer about">
<h2 class="text-center wowload fadeInUp">About Us</h2>  
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 wowload fadeInLeft nick">
      <img src="images/nick.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 wowload fadeInRight">
      <h2 class="subheading">Designed by professional , the benefit for creative gigs</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia vel labore, deleniti minima nisi, velit atque quaerat impedit ea maxime sunt accusamus at obcaecati dolor iure iusto omnis quis eum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis commodi odit, illo, qui aliquam dol</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Me gustaría que llevara al punto exacto donde está colocado el id="about"

Ya que me lleva donde termina el margen inferior del 1º elemento hijo:

```
<h2 class="text-center wowload fadeInUp animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInUp;">About Us</h2>
```

[image: Antes de pulsar el enlace del menu "about" para ir a la 2º sección]

[image: Después del pulsar el enlace del menu "about"]

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega el código completo de tu html para que podamos ver muy bien el error.

Comment: Espero ahora sea más clara

Comment: Podrías colocar tu CSS, ahí podría encontrarse el detalle..